# Shift of Equilibrium

Tags: equilibrium

A friend of mine stumbled upon this question while revising equilibrium. Apparently the answer is A.

[image]

The answer obviously cannot include adding a catalyst. Furthermore, according to le Chatelier's principle, as temperature increases, the side with the endothermic reaction is favoured, in this case 2NO<sub>(g)</sub>. Also, if there is an increase  in pressure, the side with fewer moles of gas will be favoured as it consumes more moles of gas. However, as both sides of the reaction have an equal amount of moles of gas, I would believe this to not have any effect and thus answer C. Hence, how come the answer is A?

Comment: By mistake, that's how. Your reasoning is fine.

Comment: You cannot apply Le Châtelier's principle to temperature. The effect is correct, but the reasoning is wrong. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/62852/le-ch%c3%a2teliers-principle-and-heat

Comment: @Zhe I stated that as temperature increases, the side with the endothermic reaction is favoured. I did not provide any reasoning for this.

Comment: It is really disappointing how many  exam papers contain errors.

Comment: Application of the Le Châtelier's Principle for a temperature effect is evidence of the incorrect reasoning. It gives the correct answer but for the wrong reason.

Comment: @Zhe So my textbook is incorrect?

Comment: If your textbook is using Le Châtelier's Principle to talk about the temperature dependence of equilibra, then yes, it's wrong.